# How to make Gmail recognize email as encrypted?

Tags: email, encryption, gmail

We have SSL on our email servers.

Yet we still see this un-encrypted icon on the emails we send to gmail users.

here is our MX report: 
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=popteam.io

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that lock icon, you have not implemented TLS (Transport Layer Security). Google [recently posted a descripion](https://blog.returnpath.com/attention-marketers-gmails-recent-announcement-has-big-implications-for-your-email-program/?utm_content=buffer4a175&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) of this behavior.

To resolve it, go through the steps in this [Gmail checklist](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520500?hl=en). Since you see the lock icon, at least one of these steps still needs to be done.

Comment: we are not on Gmail Apps.. but adding DMARC solved it! thanks for the links!